# Create XEN Configuration file for existing image

Tags: xen

Yesterday my system partion was damaged...afer replacing, reinstalling etc. I am now stuck that I would like to re-use my xen images. I still have the original disk and swap image, but unfortunatly not the config file.

Since I dont have enough space to backup them..I fear that xen maybe overwrites them, instead of using.

Can someone tell me the exact command so that xen re-uses the image? .... Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any other xen config files that you can copy from?  For example, in my environment, I might do this:

```
cp /etc/xen/GOODMACHINE.cfg /etc/xen/MISSING.cfg
#edit MISSING.cfg to change the disk device names (since that what we use in our environment) and mac address (and ip address if you have that in your config file)
xm create -c MISSING.cfg   #<<< watch for things that may not be working right
```

If you don't have one that you can copy from, can you just make a new machine to copy from?

Comment: +1 The Xen config won't overwrite anything. It will give out a lot if you put incorrect options in there, but it won't rewrite data already on the partitions.